# Authenticating bigcommerce using zapier and javascript

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce, zapier

I am trying to authenticate using javascript through `Zapier` but I am unable to authenticate. I am using the following code:

```
var auth = 'Basic **************';
var url = 'https://www.*****.com/api/v2/customers?email=mel****.com';


$.ajax({
    url : url,
    method : 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend : function(req) {
        req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('done');
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(request.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

However I keep receiving a `401 unauthenticated user` error. I have tried running it from an https site but can't get it to work. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that you are using http://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/. HTTPS should be on TLS 1.1 or higher. We try to avoid accepting client side ajax request to the API as it isn't a secure way to store API credentials

Comment: The error says 401, so it is an authentication error (invalid credentials), nothing else. Indeed making client side requests is insecure as anyone can get your API credentials by viewing the page source; however, the BC API makes no distinguishments on the request source, and most certainly will freely accept client-side ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base64 encode your `username:password` credentials.

`var auth = 'Basic ' +window.btoa('username:password');`